# Existence of a holomorphic function on unit disc such that Re(f) = u, for u a twice continuously differentiable and harmonic real-valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u$ be a real-valued function defined on the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$. Suppose that $u$ is twice continuously differentiable and harmonic. That is,

$$\Delta u(x, y) = 0$$

for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{D}$.

---

*Precisely, this means that
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$$
right?*

---

Prove that there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc such that $Re(f) = u$. Also show that the imaginary part of $f$ is uniquely defined up to an additive (real) constant.

**My questions:**

The problem gives a hint that states we have

$$f'(z) = \frac{2\partial u}{\partial z}$$

---

*Why are this and the below equation true?*

---

Therefore, we can let

$$g(z) = \frac{2 \partial u}{\partial z}$$

and prove that $g$ is holomorphic. Why can we find an $F$ with $F' = g$? Prove that $Re(F)$ differs from $u$ by a real constant.

---

I'm a little confused at how to approach this problem, as well as the notation used... (my questions are in italics, and are separated by page divisions). What exactly is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ if $u$ is a real-valued function? How do I approach the proof?

Comment: In order to proceed you can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. This gives you $g(z)$. Use the chain rule to switch from $∂_z$ to $∂_x$ and $∂_y$.

Answer (score 4):

For any function $h\colon \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ it is defined that
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \frac12 \left( \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} \right).$$
In particular, $u$ is such a function, so the above definition shows what $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ means.

Now, a holomorphic function $f\colon U \subset \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ has the property that, if $f = u + iv$, then
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$
These are called the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Furthermore, it is not hard to see that also
$$f' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \ \left( = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right),$$
the second equation being an immediate consequence of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Using them, it is easy to see that if $f = u + iv$ is holomorphic, then $f'(z) = \frac{2 \partial u}{\partial z}$.

Now what you are to do is to take this function $g = \frac{2 \partial u}{\partial z}$ and show that it is holomorphic. To do this, the easiest way would be to show that $g$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations (they work in both ways!). This should not be hard, since this is basically just your assumption on $u$: We have $g = s + it$ where $s = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $t = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, so, for example
$$\frac{\partial s}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = -\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial t}{\partial y}.$$

The last step is to show that $g$ has an antiderivative $F$. This is true because $g$ is a holomorphic function on a simply connected region. To construct $F$, fix a point $z_0$ in the domain (i. e., the unit disc). For every $z$ in the domain define
$$F(z) = \int_{\gamma} g(w) dw, \quad \text{where $\gamma$ is a path from $z_0$ to $z$}.$$
That this actually works is not too hard to see if you know some theory behind it. Basically, we use the fact that the path integral of $g$ is equal for homotopic paths (in particular, it is $0$ on closed loops). Some basic calculations with the integral show that indeed $F' = g$.

Finally $F - f$ has zero derivative, so is constant.

Comment: Thanks! Could you speak more about showing why $g$ has an antiderivative $F$?

Comment: Also, should the second equation read $f' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

Comment: Finally, for sake of completion, could you show that $u$ satisfies the C-R equations?

Comment: I edited my answer to include some more information. Depending on your background in complex analysis, my explanation for the existence of $F$ might be over your head. I don't want to give a whole introduction to complex analysis in this post, so if you want some more explanations on the topic, we might also meet in some chat room (just ask here in the comments).